# Calculate distortion parameters using F-theta chart

Tags: camera-calibration, fisheye

I have a working fisheye camera for which I have fx, fy(in pixel and in mm) values. I also have cx,cy(in pixel) values. I have been given an optical distortion value in %. And also I have an F-theta chart.
The F-theta chart contains values as such:

Rotation along y axis(deg), it's corresponding: tan displacement, distortion%.

I am not sure how to use this data to undistort the fisheye images. Or how to get k1,k2,k3 and k4 distortion parameters from them.

Best regards
Tahera